# Visual Studio Code adding lines between code in Python terminal causing syntax errors

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm running Python code in VS Code (1.28.2, with the Python, and Python Extension Pack extensions) and am using the 'Run Selection/Line in Python Terminal' (Shift+Enter) functionality to just run selected code in the Python terminal.

This has always worked well, but today I'm getting a new line added between each line of code in the terminal, i.e. if I ran:

```
import heapq 
import pickle
```

the output in the terminal would be:

```
>>>import heapq
>>>
>>>import pickle
```

At first, this just seems like an annoyance, but any for loops or functions now come out with an indentation error...so essentially I can't successfully run any code.

I've tried re-installing VS Code as well as installing an older version of VS Code but all give the same problem.

It's so odd because it was working fine and then all of a sudden it changed.  The only thing I can think of that has possibly changed is I installed the JSON Tools extension, but I don't believe this would change anything within Python (and I've tried uninstalling this, and not loading it again when reinstalling VS Code from scratch)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This sounds like a bug that should be a github issue in the VS code repo and not a SO question.

Comment: Before reinstalling, did you try to delete the VS Code folder located by default in `%APPDATA%\Code\User\ ` ?  (see [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations) for default locations of other OSes)

Comment: Yes, I did remove the.vscode folder (which contained the extensions) to ensure I started from a clean slate.  It seems like an error with an update of the Python extension so as per @DeepSpace's comment, I will look to post on the VS repo, or more specifically the Python extension issues page. Thanks!

Comment: It is a bug that has a fix that will go out in a point release shortly: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/2857

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's [a bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/2857) that will be fixed in the `2018.9.1` release of the Python extension.