# Unable to debug Python in VScode

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

Whenever I try to debug any python code in VScode (or even visual studio), I run into errors before it reaches the first line of code (or so it would seem). I was able to debug in both VScode and Visual Studio ~18hrs ago on both my laptop and my desktop computers before taking a break. As of ~4hrs ago, I kept running into the errors when trying to run the debug. I am able to run code through python.exe without a problem through the cmd.exe `C:\Python\Python37-32\python.exe C:\Coding\Codecademy\Python\one.py`.

I have tried uninstalling VScode, Visual Studio, and python, as well as deleted all files pertaining to any VScode or Visual studio. I then reinstalled VScode and python 3.7, though the errors still occur in the terminal. This occurs even with a simple `print("Hello World")`.

I am currently using the Python extension from Microsoft with no other extensions installed.

The error code is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\kyrus\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.0\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_process_net_command.py", line 841, in process_net_command
    py_db.writer.add_command(cmd)
  File "c:\Users\kyrus\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.0\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 448, in add_command
    self.cmdQueue.put(cmd)
AttributeError: 'Queue' object has no attribute 'put'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\kyrus\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.0\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_process_net_command.py", line 841, in process_net_command
    py_db.writer.add_command(cmd)
  File "c:\Users\kyrus\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.0\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 448, in add_command
    self.cmdQueue.put(cmd)
AttributeError: 'Queue' object has no attribute 'put'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\kyrus\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.0\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 411, in _on_run
    self.process_command(cmd_id, int(args[1]), args[2])
  File "c:\Users\kyrus\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.0\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 426, in process_command
    self.process_net_command(self.global_debugger_holder.global_dbg, cmd_id, seq, text)
  File "c:\Users\kyrus\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.0\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_process_net_command.py", line 859, in process_net_command
    py_db.writer.add_command(cmd)
  File "c:\Users\kyrus\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.0\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 448, in add_command
    self.cmdQueue.put(cmd)
AttributeError: 'Queue' object has no attribute 'put'
Can't process net command: 501  1000000000      1.1     WINDOWS ID
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
Exception in thread pydevd.Reader:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\kyrus\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.0\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_process_net_command.py", line 841, in process_net_command
    py_db.writer.add_command(cmd)
  File "c:\Users\kyrus\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.0\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 448, in add_command
    self.cmdQueue.put(cmd)
AttributeError: 'Queue' object has no attribute 'put'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\kyrus\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.0\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 411, in _on_run
    self.process_command(cmd_id, int(args[1]), args[2])
  File "c:\Users\kyrus\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.0\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 426, in process_command
    self.process_net_command(self.global_debugger_holder.global_dbg, cmd_id, seq, text)
  File "c:\Users\kyrus\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.0\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_process_net_command.py", line 845, in process_net_command
    traceback.print_exc()
  File "C:\Python\Python37-32\lib\traceback.py", line 159, in print_exc
    print_exception(*sys.exc_info(), limit=limit, file=file, chain=chain)
  File "C:\Python\Python37-32\lib\traceback.py", line 101, in print_exception
    print(line, file=file, end="")
  File "c:\Users\kyrus\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.0\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_io.py", line 30, in write
    r.write(s)
  File "c:\Users\kyrus\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.0\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 1242, in write
    py_db.writer.add_command(cmd)
  File "c:\Users\kyrus\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.0\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 448, in add_command
    self.cmdQueue.put(cmd)
AttributeError: 'Queue' object has no attribute 'put'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\kyrus\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.0\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 413, in _on_run
    traceback.print_exc()
  File "C:\Python\Python37-32\lib\traceback.py", line 159, in print_exc
    print_exception(*sys.exc_info(), limit=limit, file=file, chain=chain)
  File "C:\Python\Python37-32\lib\traceback.py", line 101, in print_exception
    print(line, file=file, end="")
  File "c:\Users\kyrus\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.0\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_io.py", line 30, in write
    r.write(s)
  File "c:\Users\kyrus\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.0\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 1242, in write
    py_db.writer.add_command(cmd)
  File "c:\Users\kyrus\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.0\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 448, in add_command
    self.cmdQueue.put(cmd)
AttributeError: 'Queue' object has no attribute 'put'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\kyrus\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.0\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 321, in run
    self._on_run()
  File "c:\Users\kyrus\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.0\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 418, in _on_run
    traceback.print_exc()
  File "C:\Python\Python37-32\lib\traceback.py", line 159, in print_exc
    print_exception(*sys.exc_info(), limit=limit, file=file, chain=chain)
  File "C:\Python\Python37-32\lib\traceback.py", line 101, in print_exception
    print(line, file=file, end="")
  File "c:\Users\kyrus\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.0\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_io.py", line 30, in write
    r.write(s)
  File "c:\Users\kyrus\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.0\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 1242, in write
    py_db.writer.add_command(cmd)
  File "c:\Users\kyrus\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.0\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 448, in add_command
    self.cmdQueue.put(cmd)
AttributeError: 'Queue' object has no attribute 'put'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "c:\Users\kyrus\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.0\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 324, in run
    traceback.print_exc()
  File "C:\Python\Python37-32\lib\traceback.py", line 159, in print_exc
    print_exception(*sys.exc_info(), limit=limit, file=file, chain=chain)
  File "C:\Python\Python37-32\lib\traceback.py", line 101, in print_exception
    print(line, file=file, end="")
  File "c:\Users\kyrus\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.0\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_io.py", line 30, in write
    r.write(s)
  File "c:\Users\kyrus\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.0\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 1242, in write
    py_db.writer.add_command(cmd)
  File "c:\Users\kyrus\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.0\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 448, in add_command
    self.cmdQueue.put(cmd)
AttributeError: 'Queue' object has no attribute 'put'
Unhandled exception in thread started by Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Thread._bootstrap of <ReaderThread(pydevd.Reader, started daemon 1916)>>

Traceback (most recent call last):


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:



During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:



During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:



During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:



During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


Traceback (most recent call last):

Traceback (most recent call last):
Exception in thread pydevd.CheckAliveThread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\kyrus\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.0\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 321, in run
    self._on_run()
  File "c:\Users\kyrus\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.0\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 185, in _on_run
    if not self.py_db.has_threads_alive() and self.py_db.writer.empty():
  File "c:\Users\kyrus\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.0\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 488, in empty
    return self.cmdQueue.empty()
AttributeError: 'Queue' object has no attribute 'empty'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "c:\Users\kyrus\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.0\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 324, in run
    traceback.print_exc()
  File "C:\Python\Python37-32\lib\traceback.py", line 159, in print_exc
    print_exception(*sys.exc_info(), limit=limit, file=file, chain=chain)
  File "C:\Python\Python37-32\lib\traceback.py", line 101, in print_exception
    print(line, file=file, end="")
  File "c:\Users\kyrus\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.0\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_io.py", line 30, in write
    r.write(s)
  File "c:\Users\kyrus\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.0\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 1242, in write
    py_db.writer.add_command(cmd)
  File "c:\Users\kyrus\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.0\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 448, in add_command
    self.cmdQueue.put(cmd)
AttributeError: 'Queue' object has no attribute 'put'
Unhandled exception in thread started by Unhandled exception in thread started by <_pydev_bundle.pydev_monkey._NewThreadStartupWithTrace object at 0x0405B7F0>

Traceback (most recent call last):


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:



During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


Unhandled exception in thread started by Unhandled exception in thread started by <_pydev_bundle.pydev_monkey._NewThreadStartupWithTrace object at 0x04096B10>

Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Update:
The problem still persists, but I've noticed another area where it seems to throw an similar error regarding python (relating to the 'Queue' object). Whenever I try to install a linter, it throws the following error in the terminal:

```
PS C:\Coding\Codecademy\Python> & C:/Python/Python37/python.exe -m pip install -U pep8 --user
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\__main__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main as _main  # noqa
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 58, in <module>
    class ConnectionPool(object):
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 65, in ConnectionPool
    QueueCls = queue.LifoQueue
AttributeError: module 'queue' has no attribute 'LifoQueue'
PS C:\Coding\Codecademy\Python>
```

Comment: Looks like something went terribly wrong with VS code and Python today: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52873612/

Comment: Ever found out what was the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try checking your python version I faced similar errors when I was trying to run my python3 code in VScode. Try changing the python version in vscode.

Comment: I tried 3.6 just now and the same error occurred. As I mentioned before, the debugger worked less than 24hrs ago with the exact same version of python.

Comment: try some other version.

Comment: Switching versions does not fix the problem.

Comment: Try to run your code in Linux using virtual environment.

Comment: How is this even related to my problem? I can run the code fine using command line. The issue is with VSCode and python. I can't debug or install linters (and I assume other things). This occurred on both my laptop and desktop at the same time. This is after everything was working fine a day ago.

Comment: Then Uninstall VSCode, Clear all VScode preferences (do a backup in case you need them later), reinstall VScode, install extension, best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

If this helps anyone, I had a situation where all of a sudden my Python code didn't seem to be debugging In VS Code anymore.  There would be a brief change of color in the status bar at bottom and that's all.  It turned out to be due to a blank line accidentally getting inserted into the code before the line containing "main()".  I removed it and voila!